# How to fix ephemeral local storage problem?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm Running some deployment on EKS k8s 1.16 and after ~5 min my pod gets Evicted with the following message:

```
Pod ephemeral local storage usage exceeds the total limit of containers 1Gi.
```

My node has 20Gi ephemeral storage.

My QoS Class is Guaranteed and no matter which amount of ephemeral-storage I configure in my yaml, I see the same error with the amount I configure.

Do you have a clue what can be done?

My yaml file is here: https://slexy.org/view/s2096sex7L

Answer (score 7):

It's because you're putting an upper limit of `ephemeral-storage` usage by setting `resources.limits.ephemeral-storage` to `1Gi`. Remove the `limits.ephemeral-storage` if safe, or change the value depending upon your requirement.

```yaml
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: "61Gi"
          cpu: "7500m"
          ephemeral-storage: "1Gi" <----- here
        requests:
          memory: "61Gi"
          cpu: "7500m"
          ephemeral-storage: "1Gi"
```

- [Requests and limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#requests-and-limits)

> If the node where a Pod is running has enough of a resource available, it’s possible (and allowed) for a container to use more resources than its request for that resource specifies. However, a container is **not allowed** to use more than its resource `limit`.

Comment: Is there a way we can monitor this and know about it before eviction?

Answer (score 5):

If you're reading this and you're using GKE Autopilot, there is a hard limit of 10G for ephemeral storage in Autopilot. I would recommend moving your storage to a Volume.

See Autopilot documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview#allowable_resource_ranges)